# SQLAlchemy's "post_update" behaves differently with objects that have been expunged from a session

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to copy rows from one DB instance to a another DB with an identical schema in a different environment. Two tables within this schema are linked in such a way that they result in mutually dependent rows. When these rows are inserted, the `post_update` runs afterward as expected, but the update statement sets the value of the ID field to `None` instead of the expected ID.

This *only* happens when using objects that have been expunged from a session. When using newly created objects, the `post_update` behaves exactly as expected.

**Examples**

I have a relationship set up that looks like this:

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    top_product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'))
    products = relationship('Product', primaryjoin='Product.category_id == Category.id', back_populates='category', cascade='all', lazy='selectin')
    top_product = relationship('Product', primaryjoin='Category.top_product_id == Product.id', post_update=True, cascade='all', lazy='selectin')


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = relationship('Category', primaryjoin='Product.category_id == Category.id', back_populates='products', cascade='all', lazy='selectin')
```

If I query a category and its related products from one DB and try to write them to another, the update of `top_product_id` doesn't behave as expected, and sets the value to `None` instead. The following code:

```
category = source_session.query(Category).filter(Category.id == 99).one()
source_session.expunge(category)
make_transient(category)
for products in category.products:
    make_transient(product)
# this step is necessary to prevent a foreign key error on the initial category insert
category.top_product_id = None
dest_session.add(category)
```

results in SQLAlchemy generating the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO categories (name, top_product_id) VALUES (%s, %s)
('SomeCategoryName', None)
INSERT INTO products (name, category_id) VALUES (%s, %s)
('SomeProductName', 99)
UPDATE categories SET top_product_id=%s WHERE categories.id = %s
(None, 99)
```

But if I use newly created objects, everything works as expected.

```
category = Category()
product = Product()
category.name = 'SomeCategoryName'
product.name = 'SomeProductName'
product.category = category
category.top_product = product
dest_session.add(category)
```

results in:

```
INSERT INTO categories (name, top_product_id) VALUES (%s, %s)
('SomeCategoryName', None)
INSERT INTO products (name, category_id) VALUES (%s, %s)
('SomeProductName', 99)
UPDATE categories SET top_product_id=%s WHERE categories.id = %s
(1, 99)
```

Aside from this difference, everything behaves in the same way between these two actions. All other relationship are created properly, IDs and foreign keys are set as expected. Only the `top_product_id` set in the update clause created by the `post_update` fails to behave as expected.

As an additional troubleshooting step, I tried:

1. Creating new objects
2. Adding them to a session
3. Flushing the session to the DB
4. Expunging the objects from the session
5. Unseting the foreign key ID fields on the objects (to avoid initial insert error) and making the objects transient
6. Re-adding the objects to the session
7. Re-flushing to the DB

On the first flush to the DB, the `top_product_id` is set properly. On the second, it's set to `None`. So this confirms that the issue is not with differences in the sessions, but something to do with expunging objects from sessions and making them transient. There must be *something* that does/doesn't happen during the expunge/make transient process that leaves these objects in a fundamentally different state and prevents `post_update` from behaving the way it should.

Any ideas on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `Base` class mixes in the `name` column?

Your goal is to make `inspect(category).committed_state` look like it does for newly created objects (except maybe for `id` attribute). Same for each product object.

In your "newly created objects" example, `category`'s `committed_state` looks like this before flushing the session:

```
{'id': symbol('NEVER_SET'),
 'name': symbol('NO_VALUE'),
 'products': [],
 'top_product': symbol('NEVER_SET')}
```

while `product`'s `committed_state` looks like this:

```
{'category': symbol('NEVER_SET'),
 'id': symbol('NEVER_SET'),
 'name': symbol('NO_VALUE')}
```

To get the post-update behavior, you need to both expire `category.top_product_id` (to prevent it from being included in the `INSERT`) and fudge `category.top_product`'s `committed_state` (to make SQLAlchemy believe that the value has changed and therefore needs to cause an `UPDATE`).

First, expire `category.top_product_id` before making `category` transient:

```
source_session.expire(category, ["top_product_id"])
```

Then fudge `category.top_product`'s `committed_state` (this can happen before or after making `category` transient):

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm.base import NEVER_SET
inspect(category).committed_state.update(top_product=NEVER_SET)
```

Full example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, make_transient, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.base import NEVER_SET

class Base(object):
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    top_product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'))
    products = relationship('Product', primaryjoin='Product.category_id == Category.id', back_populates='category', cascade='all', lazy='selectin')
    top_product = relationship('Product', primaryjoin='Category.top_product_id == Product.id', post_update=True, cascade='all', lazy='selectin')


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'), nullable=False)
    category = relationship('Category', primaryjoin='Product.category_id == Category.id', back_populates='products', cascade='all', lazy='selectin')


source_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
dest_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)

def fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):
    dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

from sqlalchemy import event
for engine in [source_engine, dest_engine]:
    event.listen(engine, 'connect', fk_pragma_on_connect)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=source_engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=dest_engine)

source_session = Session(bind=source_engine)
dest_session = Session(bind=dest_engine)

source_category = Category(id=99, name='SomeCategoryName')
source_product = Product(category=source_category, id=100, name='SomeProductName')
source_category.top_product = source_product
source_session.add(source_category)
source_session.commit()
source_session.close()

# If you want to test UPSERTs in dest_session.
# dest_category = Category(id=99, name='PrevCategoryName')
# dest_product = Product(category=dest_category, id=100, name='PrevProductName')
# dest_category.top_product = dest_product
# dest_session.add(dest_category)
# dest_session.commit()
# dest_session.close()

category = source_session.query(Category).filter(Category.id == 99).one()
# Ensure relationship attributes are initialized before we make objects transient.
_ = category.top_product
# source_session.expire(category, ['id'])  # only if you want new IDs in dest_session
source_session.expire(category, ['top_product_id'])
for product in category.products:
    # Ensure relationship attributes are initialized before we make objects transient.
    _ = product.category
    # source_session.expire(product, ['id'])  # only if you want new IDs in dest_session
    # Not strictly needed as long as Product.category is not a post-update relationship.
    source_session.expire(product, ['category_id'])

make_transient(category)
inspect(category).committed_state.update(top_product=NEVER_SET)

for product in category.products:
    make_transient(product)
    # Not strictly needed as long as Product.category is not a post-update relationship.
    inspect(product).committed_state.update(category=NEVER_SET)

dest_session.add(category)
# Or, if you want UPSERT (must retain original IDs in this case)
# dest_session.merge(category)
dest_session.flush()
```

Which produces this DML in `dest_session`:

```
INSERT INTO categories (name, id, top_product_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
('SomeCategoryName', 99, None)
INSERT INTO products (name, id, category_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
('SomeProductName', 100, 99)
UPDATE categories SET top_product_id=? WHERE categories.id = ?
(100, 99)
```

It seems like `make_transient` should reset `committed_state` to be as if it were a new object, but I guess not.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! I'll test out these changes when I get a chance and will mark this answer as accepted assuming it works.

Comment: It works! Thanks again. Its worth noting that this is still pretty fragile. I tried removing the line `inspect(product).committed_state.update(category=NEVER_SET)`, which as you pointed out shouldn't be necessary, but that broke the product.category_id foreign key update and resulted in an error on insert. Still, this is much better than the hacks I was resorting to without it!